# Why am I getting syntax error on 'excpet'?

Tags: python, syntax, compiler-errors, except

I don't know why i'm getting a syntax error on 'excpet'. All seems well to me! Here's my code:

```
def length():
gameLength = int(input("How many words do you want to play? You can chose anywhere from 1-40: "))
global gameLength
if gameLength <= 40 and gameLength >= 1:
    quit
else:
    int(input("Please choose a number between 1 & 40 "))
except ValueError = True:
     int(input("Please choose a number between 1 & 40 "))
return gameLength
```

Comment: Probably because you typed 'except' wrong?

Comment: I'm surprised you only get an error *there*. With the code you show, as you show it, you should have gotten many other errors first. Assuming this is Python of course (don't forget the language tag!).

Comment: Also, when posting questions about errors, please copy-paste the actual error output into the question. As text, in full, complete and without editing.

Comment: Lastly, please [read more about exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/errors.html) because you're not using it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent your code correctly, and add a try statement before the except. You also need to evaluate the true with '==' instead of '='.

```
def length():
    global gameLength
    gameLength = int(input("How many words do you want to play? You can chose anywhere from 1-40: "))
    if gameLength <= 40 and gameLength >= 1:
        quit
    else:
        try:
            int(input("Please choose a number between 1 & 40 "))
        except ValueError == True:
            int(input("Please choose a number between 1 & 40 "))
    return gameLength
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
First, you got to indent your function (not the main error). Now on to the next errors:
1. You must have a try statement before having an except. Also, rather than repeating the same function, you should use return ValueError. Here, I modified the code but made it what you desired:

```
try:
    if gameLength <= 40 and gameLength >= 1:
        quit
    else:
        return ValueError
except ValueError: // or except ValueError == true
    length()
```

2. Look at the line with `except ValueError = true:`. One equal sign means you are assigning ValueError to equal true, like you say `x = 10`. Two equal signs mean that you are asking, "does it equal true?", like saying
    `1 + 5 == 6` will return true, because 1+5 IS 6. Now go back to your ValueError.
   Change your except line with: `except ValueError == true`. Now you're asking, "is the ValueError equal to true?" rather than saying, "ValueError MUST equal true!" You can also say `except ValueError` because if statements and other statements always go if it returns true. For example, `if true:` will work or `while true` will go on forever, but `if 1+1==3:` will never work, because 1+1==3 returns false.
3. Assign gameLength as a global variable before assigning it a value.
4. Put gameLength in the try statement:

   ```
   try:
       gameLength = int(input("How many..."))
   ```

   Why? Because if you put it before the try statement and the input was, for instance, "hi", you can't make "hi" an integer. Try statements **try** to do something, and after failing, doesn't just give up and return an error, but does what the programmer wants it to do. In this case, we want it to repeat the function, so we will do length() on the except. And that's
5. repeating the function over and over.

   ```
   except ValueError:
       print("Please type a number from 1-40.")
       length()
   ```

   Finally, I'll change one more thing:
6. quit is a function. Make it quit(), or it won't quit, as you expected.

**Output (And Code)**

```
def length():
    global gameLength

    try:
        gameLength = int(input("How many words do you want to play? You can choose any number from 1-40: "))
        if gameLength <= 40 and gameLength >= 1:
            quit()
        else:
            return ValueError
    except ValueError:
         print("Please type a number from 1-40.")
         length()
    return gameLength

length()
```

> **IDLE**: How many words do you want to play? You can choose any number from 1-40:
>   **ME**: "I'm a string."
>   **IDLE**: Please type a number from 1-40.
>   **IDLE**: How many words do you want to play? You choose any number from 1-40:
>   **ME**: 54919
>   **IDLE**: Please type a number from 1-40.
>   **IDLE**: How many words do you want to play? You choose any number from 1-40:
>   **ME**: 37.1
>   *Making number an integer: 37.1 => 37.
>   **CON**: 37
>   *Quitting Python.*